# NuGet add reference error while installing Localytics packages

Tags: c#-4.0, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

I am not able to install Localytics package by Nuget. For example when I want install Localytics I receive following error:

```
PM> Install-Package Localytics
```

Installing 'Localytics 3.1.0'.
Successfully installed 'Localytics 3.1.0'.
Adding 'Localytics 3.1.0' to NewDemo.
Uninstalling 'Localytics 3.1.0'.
Successfully uninstalled 'Localytics 3.1.0'.
Install failed. Rolling back...
Install-Package : Could not install package 'Localytics 3.1.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'WindowsPhone,Version=v8.1', but the package 
does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Localytics
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand